# Capture mac screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, record, recording

What is the best way to record the mac screen with cocoa? I know there are many examples at the apple developer reference library. SonOfGrab explain how to capture the screen with quartz but also that it isn't enough fast to use it to grab many frames every second. OpenGLScreenSnapshot has same results but it isn't fast, too. OpenGLScreenCapture seems to be the best way to do it but XCode prompts me many errors because it's made for 10.4 and it requires old Quicktime commands I think they pushed into QTKit but I can't find a way to convert it. Could anyone send me to someone's site that converted the project or tell me if there are some other ways to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL would be the way to go.  You should still be able to use the OpenGLScreenCapture sample if your architecture is set to 32-bit. (QuickTime is not available in 64-bit.)

-Ken

Comment: Yes I can open the sample application but I want to compile it, to make some changes! It writes that a lot of ICM things are missing

Comment: Yes,you need to turn off 64-bit architecture.