# Compiling Apple's OpenGLCaptureToMovie sample under 10.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I see that Apple's [OpenGLScreenCapture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/Introduction/Intro.html) sample was originally created in the days of 10.4, and now I'm having trouble compiling it under Snow Leopard 10.6 (Xcode 4).  I've changed the build settings to my native architecture and 10.6 base SDK, but I get tons of errors like "Expected * before *". Is this some kind of problem with LLVM? What do I need to do to get this to compile in Snow Leopard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843271/capture-mac-screen).  It will only run as 32-bit.  Won't run as 64-bit.